# Altura da div é maior que a altura da imagem. Por quê?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tenho o seguinte HTML puro, sem CSS

```
<div>
  <img src="_img/_banner/banner1.jpg" />
</div>
```

A imagem **banner1.jpg** possui `300px` de **altura** e à `div` não foram estabelecidas dimensões.

Olhando no `inspector` para a `imagem` temos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Olhando no `inspector` para a `div` temos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nota-se que, embora no *inspector* não haja `borders`, `paddings`, `margins`, nada para a imagem, ela está de alguma maneira aumentando a altura da `div` para `304px`.

Gostaria de entender o porquê disso, sendo que que não há medidas extras atreladas nem à `img` nem à `div`.

Sei que aplicar `display:block` à **imagem**, resolve o problema, mas não consigo entender porquê!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O elemento `img` possui a propriedade `display` valendo [`inline`](http://htmlreference.io/element/img/) como padrão e, se não alterada, será este o valor. Elementos `inline` são exibidos seguindo as mesmas regras dos textos, da tipografia, no caso, com os mesmos espaçamentos. Os espaçamentos previstos para a tipografia são:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>Imagem retirado de [typedeck.com](http://typedeck.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/baseline.png)</sup>

Onde, simploriamente:

- *ascender height* é o espaço acima do texto, reservado para acentuações;
- *cap height* é o espaço extra utilizado para letras em caixa alta;
- *x-height* é o espaço utilizado pelas letras em caixa baixa;
- *descender height* é o espaço abaixo do texto, reservado para letras como p, q, j, e outras que possuem parte do corpo abaixo da *baseline*;

O que é importante aqui é notar a linha em vermelho: *baseline*. Todos os elementos `inline` são alinhados junto à *baseline*, inclusive as imagens, por padrão. Os 4px que surgem na `div` são referentes ao espaço previsto para a *descender height*, tanto que se você variar o valor de `line-height` da sua `div`, este valor irá também mudar, pois mudará o valor da *descender height*.

Quando alterado o `display` para `block`, a imagem para de seguir as regras da tipografia e o espaçamento inferior deixa de existir.

**Exemplo variando o valor de `line-height`**

```css
div {
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://i2.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/001/042/619/4ea.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Entendi e compreendi. Mas só mais uma dúvida: Não seria o caso do inspector mostrar essas medidas quando é o objeto é inline não? Pois assim ajuda a enxergar onde estão as medidas adicionais! Ou o inspector só mostra medidas do que é block?

Comment: @CarlosRocha não domino completamente o inspetor, mas acho que ele não chega nesse nível de detalhamento, não.